# Visualforce page not displaying any records when using a standard controller

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to display records by using the code below, but my visualforce page is not displaying any records.

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote__c">
<apex:pageBlock id="thePageBlock" >
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Private Event Detail" columns="1">
        <p>demo3: {!Quote__c.demo3__c}</p>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Can you please tell us how are you accessing the page?

Comment: As alluded to in the other comments/answer do you definitely have your quote object in the page? ie. The ID in the URL. If you replace {!Quote__c.demo3__c} with {!Quote__c.Id} - what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are triggering the VF like http:///Apex/?. where parameter is the information related to particular record you wanted to display. In your example in the above code, it could be the quote ID?.

Comment: In quote__c i want to display the Demo3__c field records.

Comment: <apex:page standardController="Quote__c" recordSetVar="values">
<apex:pageBlock title="value">
  <apex:pageBlockSection >
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!values}" var="pitem">
  <apex:outputText value="{!pitem.demo3__c}"/>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:pageBlockSection>

</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>

Comment: i tried like above but it not showing any records.

Comment: Check the field level security on the `demo3__c` field

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of your question is correct, demo3_*c is a field in object Quote*_c.
If that is the case then try something like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote__c" recordSetVar="quotes">  
 <apex:pageBlock >
     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!quotes}" var="quo" id="list">
       <apex:column value="{!quo.demo3__c}"/>
     </apex:pageBlockTable>   </apex:pageBlock> </apex:page>
```